# RecyclerView, pass multiple views via onClickListener to cycle through options

Tags: java, android

I have the following which lets the user click on an image and it turns the image invisible:

```
holder.redView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ManualPlayingChange.notToPlaying(view);
    }
});

public static void notToPlaying(View a) {
    if(a.isShown()) {
        a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is pass through another `View`, so that a different `Ciew` also changes on the same click.

The views I have:

```
public ViewHolder(View p) {
    super(p);
    playerView = p.findViewById(R.id.aPlayerInTheList);
    greenView = p.findViewById(R.id.isPlaying);
    amberView = p.findViewById(R.id.mightBePlaying);
    redView = p.findViewById(R.id.notPlaying);
}
```

So I just want to be able to cycle through the 3 images.

Comment: pass the `ViewHolder` inside the `notToPlaying(ViewHolder viewholder)` and access the views like : `viewholder.playerView.setVisibility(); viewholder.greenView.setVisibility();` etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what you mean but how do I call notToPlaying and then pass the holder through with the onClick??

Comment: instead of view, pass holder like `ManualPlayingChange.notToPlaying(holder);`

Comment: Just did that after I asked :) thank you!

Comment: Nice :) I wasn't clear what you want initially hence added comment. I have added it as an answer so it might be useful to someone someday!.

Comment: Please try to format your questions a bit nicer next time. It is always nice to see someone put some work into getting their question answered ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the `holder` (i.e `ViewHolder`) itself in `notToPlaying()` method instead of single `view` and then access all the views like:

```
public static void notToPlaying(ViewHolder holder){
    // now you can access all the views
    holder.playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.redView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // and so on.
}
```